# gdal hillshade problem in python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, pyqgis

I'm trying to do a gdal hillshade using this code:

```
  import os, subprocess 
  #create hillshade using gdal
  subprocess.call(["gdaldem", "hillshade", r"/data/brent/SRTM DEM Training for Zamboanga Peninsula/raw_DEM.tif", \
     r"/data/brent/SRTM DEM Training for Zamboanga Peninsula/zamb_try_hillshade.tif", "-z 1.0", "-s 111120.0", \
     "-az 315.0", "-alt 45.0", "-of GTiff"])
```

It runs in the python console but there is no resulting tif file when I checked the ouput folder. 
[image]
Did I miss something in my code? or there is a bug with gdaldem hillshade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split all the arguments in `subprocess.call` (e.g. `"-z", "1.0"` instead of `"-z 1.0"`):

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call(["gdaldem", "hillshade", r"/data/brent/SRTM DEM Training for Zamboanga Peninsula/raw_DEM.tif", \
     r"/data/brent/SRTM DEM Training for Zamboanga Peninsula/zamb_try_hillshade.tif", "-z", "1.0", "-s", "111120.0", \
     "-az", "315.0", "-alt", "45.0"])
```